# How to modify an if statement based on the strings listed in the criteria

Tags: excel, if-statement, logic, vlookup

[image]

I have two sheets of the data - sheet 1 contains the string of the number & letter combined (For example ABC1,ABC2 & ABC3) in column G3

Ultimately, I need a formula that will state "Yes" Or No" if there is an identical match between sheet 1 & sheet 2.

Comment: Post few samples from both sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to check if a concatenated string in one sheet exists within a range of another sheet.

Here's how you can adjust the formula using MATCH():

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(AA2&$AC$1,Sheet1!G3:G,0)),"Yes","No")
```